# Run multiple instances of Windows Phone 7 Emulator at same time

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am trying to launch multiple instances of Windows Phone 7 emulator at same time according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097841/how-can-i-run-multiple-instances-of-the-windows-phone-7-emulator-at-the-same-tim) and [this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/how-run-multiple-instances) posts.

But whenever an instance is already running, the new instance launches and disappears quickly without any error message. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough available RAM on your computer?

Comment: @KooKiz Oops, freed a chunk of RAM, it worked like a charm, thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opening a new instance of the emulator requires a large amount of available **physical** RAM (it doesn't use the swap). Close a few programs to free up some memory and try again.